# How to retrieve HTML Content from database and display the content in android application according to HTML Code

Tags: php, android, html

I have both web and android part for my project.
I have used an HTML Editor for a description box. When i enter any HTML description it stores in DB as HTML code like

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

And i want to fetch the data from my table and to display it as Hello(above said) in Android App.(with default styles of `h1` tag).
Please help me to find an answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't want it formatted? or you wanted it as h1 in android?

Comment: i just want to display the content not the html code as whole. if my sql table coulumn has a content like <h1>Hello</h1> , i want to dispaly it as Hello with default h1 font size: 2 em

Comment: can you add php code in question?

Comment: there is no php code to retrieve my content. i am just extracting the content without html tag using  fildname.setText(Html.fromHtml(parsed.description));

Comment: Can't you replace <h1> with '' in your code?